# Debian Stretch LXDE task manager?

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts, lxde

Whilst dropping my keyboard a few hours ago, I pressed down a few keys whilst trying to keep it in my hands. When my view returned to the screen, I saw that I had called up a Task Manager.

However, not only can I not find it in the menu, I've also used a search engine and I can't find information on how to call this up with the keyboard.

Does anyone know how to do this?

I am using LXDE.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the system monitor from the *Terminal* by typing: `gnome-system-monitor`

Alternatively, run this command by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and typing `gnome-system-monitor`.

AFAIK, There is no shortcut for `System Monitor`, you need to create one.

1. Go to **System Settings**

   1. Click **Keyboard**
   2. Click the "**+**" symbol near the bottom of the window
   3. Give your command a **title**. E.g. *System Monitor*
   4. In the **Command** field, enter `gnome-system-monitor`
   5. Enter the key combination you want for your shortcut. E.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>
   6. Click **Apply**

Or maybe it could be that you setup a shortcut before and you don't remember? Check by going into **Keyboard settings**.

Note : This answer is specifically for `gnome`.

Comment: thanks for the answer. unfortunately i forgot to say that i am using lxde

Answer (score 0):

On LXDE, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd> [opens the task manager](https://git.lxde.org/gitweb/?p=debian/lxde-common.git;a=blob;f=openbox/rc.xml.in;h=d386b8aa024eb8efb965a6544e0976a099fb09cc;hb=HEAD#l297). You can customise this by [editing the `rc.xml` configuration file](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Bindings).